# Accesing method startsWith throw error when calling console.log() in proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-proxy

I am learning about ES6 proxies, for this purpose I follow the guide on [javascript.info](http://javascript.info/proxy), the following example, avoid reading, deleting, adding a new property and listing properties if the property name starts with an underscore, for example `_password`

```
let user = {
  username: "john.doe",
  firstname: "John",
  lastname: "doe",
  email: "john.doe@example.com",
  _password: "******"
};

user = new Proxy(user, {
  get(target, property) {
    if (property.startsWith("_")) {
      throw new Error("Access denied");
    }

    return target[property];
  },

  set(target, property, value) {
    if (value.startsWith("_")) {
      throw new Error("Access denied");
    }

    target[property] = value;

    return true;
  },

  deleteProperty(target, property) {
    if (property.startsWith("_")) {
      throw new Error("Access denied");
    }

    delete target[property];

    return true;
  },

  ownKeys(target) {
    return Object.keys(target).filter(key => !key.startsWith("_"));
  }
});

const { username, firstname, lastname, email } = user;

console.log(username, firstname, lastname, email);
console.log(JSON.stringify(user, null, 2));
console.log(user);
```

The call to `console.log(JSON.stringify(user, null, 2));` show the expected output, because _password is omitted in the output

```
{
    "username": "john.doe",
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "doe",
    "email": "john.doe@example.com"
}
```

But when calling `console.log(user);` I get the following error

```
/tmp/index.js:48
    if (property.startsWith("_")) {
                 ^

TypeError: property.startsWith is not a function
```

Thanks for your comments

Comment: I ran your exact code, and  don't have any error (Chrome 76)

Comment: I am trying in Firefox 69

Comment: What if you just return the target at the top if no property is given? `if (!property) { return target; }`

Comment: Tested in Firefox 69, no issue. Edge kinda works (weird behavior), but does not throw any error either.

Comment: I'm sorry guys, I didn't give the complete information, the last tests I have done calling the script with node

I have verified that in Firefox it goes as expected

The installed node version is v10.16.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When accessing symbol-keyed properties on your proxy object (like `console.log` [does it in node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_custom)), your trap handlers get passed the symbol as the `property` argument, not a property name. A symbol doesn't have the `startsWith` string method of course. Use

```
if (typeof property == "string" && property.startsWith("_")) {
```

instead.